# How to Add Additional Values for my jQuery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to figure out how to add more values than just the 33498, any ideas?

```
function checkThis(){
  var val = document.getElementById('myText').value;
  var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  if(val=="33498")

    myForm.action="url1.html";



  else
    myForm.action="url2.html";


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```
switch (val) {
   case "33498":
       myForm.action="url1.html";
       break;
   case "xxx":
   case "yyy":
       myForm.action="another.html";
       break;
   default:
       myForm.action="url2.html";

}
```

Comment: is there a way to add multiple options in the case?

Comment: Such as:  case "33498","33497":

Comment: I am not sure of the proper syntax

Comment: Quick question,  how would I make these pages do a "_blank" to open in a new page?

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkThis() {

    var val = document.getElementById('myText').value;
    var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

    if (val == "33498") {

        myForm.action = "url1.html";

    } else if (val == "this") {

        myForm.action = "url2.html";

    } else if (val == "that") {

        myForm.action = "url3.html";

    } else if (val == "the other") {

        myForm.action = "url4.html";

    } else {

        // if all else fails   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're said, you're using jQuery....

So `document.getElementById('myText').value;` can simply be: `$('#myText').val();`

...and `document.getElementById('myForm');` can simply be: `$('#myForm')`.

You're also missing a variety of brackets, `{ }`, after your `if()` statement.

You would add more conditionals to an `if()` statement by using the `else if`, like this...

```
function checkThis(){
  var val = $('#myText').val();
  var myForm = $('#myForm');

  if(val=="33498") {
    myForm.action="url1.html";    
  } else if (val == "568") {
    myForm.action="url3.html";
  } else if (val == "999") {
    myForm.action="url4.html";
  } else {  
    myForm.action="url2.html";  // <--do this one if nothing else matches
  }

}
```